# How to pass data to a router-view in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-router

How can I pass data from my main app to a component through `router-view` in Vue.js? I have successfully gotten the data from my API as shown below:

```
mounted() {
    // console.log(model)
    this.model = model;
    // console.log(this.model)
}
```

The component I want to pass data to has been loaded as shown below:

```
@section('content')
<div style="padding: 0.9rem" id="app">
    <router-view name="bookBus"></router-view>
    <router-view></router-view>
    {{-- @{{ model }} --}}
</div>

@stop
```

How do I pass the `model` data to the `bookBus` component?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-view.html

> Any non-name props will be passed along to the rendered component, however most of the time the per-route data is contained in the route's params.

So if you want to pass data down from the parent component, rather than from the router, it would be something like this:

```
<router-view name="bookBus" :model="model"></router-view>
```

Your `bookBus` component would then need to have a `model` prop configured to receive the data, just like it would for any other prop.