# Pass value to all routes with router-view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have data of `currency` and i wish to pass this data to all views instead of calling same function in each view.

So I've decided to call my function in `App.vue (my main view)` but can't figure it how to pass it along with `router-view`

## Code

`HTML`

```
<template>
  <el-container :is="layout">
    <transition name="fade">
      <router-view id="content" :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
    </transition>
  </el-container>
</template>
```

`Script`

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        isCollapse: true,
        user: '',
        type: '',
        site_name: process.env.MIX_APP_NAME
      }
    },
    created () {
      this.getCurrency()
    },
    methods: {
      getCurrency() {
        axios
        .get('/api/currencyDefault')
        .then(response => {
          this.currency = response.data.data
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('error', error);
        });
      },
    }
}
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: why not use vuex for that ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 I am using vuex for handling login/register/etc. if you want i can provide full code maybe you have better idea than mine :)

Comment: please read my answer

Comment: nowhere :/.  i just tried to access currency in my main view like this `{{currency.name}}`

Comment: you must call getCurrency function in the component where you pass also the router view

Comment: like this? `computed: {
            getCurrency()
        },`

Comment: no, you already did it right ? As what you had presented.

Comment: Ok i'm confused now.  My `App.vue` is like what you see in question + your `props:['currency'] / :currency="currency"` and now in my mainpage component i have this `{{currency.name}}` so do i need anything else in anywhere?

Comment: props:['currency'] this one will be called by other views you wanted to access the currency. Nothing more.

Comment: exactly, but the issue is i get error no currency values

Comment: is your router view and get currency is not in the same component ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass that currency to the router view by doing it like this

```
    <template>
      <el-container :is="layout">
        <transition name="fade">
           <router-view :currency="currency"id="content" :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
        </transition>
      </el-container>
    </template>

export default {
    data() {
      return {
        isCollapse: true,
        user: '',
        type: '',
        site_name: process.env.MIX_APP_NAME
      }
    },
    created () {
      this.getCurrency()
    },
    methods: {
      getCurrency() {
        axios
        .get('/api/currencyDefault')
        .then(response => {
          this.currency = response.data.data
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('error', error);
        });
      },
    }
}
```

now in your other view you could access it through props, like this

```
export default {
    props:['currency']
}
```

but the problem with this approach is like, when you have a deeper child component and you still want to access this currency data, then you have to pass again props to another router view which is sooner it will take you to having hard time in handling it. My suggest is to use Vuex for this. Since this currency is available to all of your views.

see docs here [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

Comment: Property or method "currency" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Comment: where did you access prop currency ? in must be in your component that will be using.

Comment: I tried to get currency data in my main page, main page is printing inside app.vue -> router-view

Comment: and your getCurrency  ? where did you put it ?

Comment: Question due: why if i try to move this function from `app.vue` to `store.js` where my vuex methods are. it won't return any data? do you have sample of this maybe you could share a link?

Comment: When you put in store.js ? then you have to dispatch the action when your page loaded.

Comment: hmm, by dispatch it says `function () { [native code] }`

Comment: how you dispatched that action ?

Comment: i will make different question for it.

Comment: here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890045/vuex-dispatch-doesnt-return-data-in-view

Answer (score 1):

You can pass down props to the router view and it will be passed along to the child component. This stackoverflow answers your question -> [How to pass data to a router-view in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49696424/how-to-pass-data-to-a-router-view-in-vue-js)

```
<router-view :currency="currency"></router-view>
```

One issue I noticed, you set `this.currency` in your api call, which will overwrite the method you have called the same thing. Maybe change the name of your method to `getCurrency`.

```
methods: {
  getCurrency () {
    axios
    .get('/api/currencyDefault')
    .then(response => {
      this.currency = response.data.data
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    });
  },
}
```

Comment: t says `Property or method "currency" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. `

Comment: It wasn't added to the data, so that is why that error is showing up