# Vuex dispatch doesn't return data in view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I cannot get my data from vuex and use them in all views, but i do see their success results in network tab.

## screenshots

`network tab`

[image: one]

`console`

[image: two]

## Code

`store.js`

```
state: {
    currency: {}
},
mutations: {
    currency(state, currency){
      state.currency = currency
    }
},
actions: {
    currency({commit}){
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commit('currency')
        axios({url: '/api/currencyDefault', method: 'GET' })
        .then(resp => {
          const currency = resp.data.data
          commit('currency', currency)
          resolve(resp)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          commit('currency')
          reject(err)
        })
      })
    },
},
getters: {
    currency: state => state.currency,
}
```

`App.vue (main component where routers will load)`

```
<script>
export default {
  props:['currency'],
  data() {
    return {
      isCollapse: true,
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.currency()
  },
  methods: {
    currency() {
      this.$store.dispatch('currency')
   }
  },
}
</script>
```

An then in my other component i call for currency like:

```
{{currency.name}}
```

**ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method Currency is already defined as props. remove this in your code.

```
props:['currency']
```

Ten call this currency in your component like this

```
<div>
   {{this.$store.getters.currency.name}}
</div>
```

to surely display the currency, what I did is to put first a condition to check if it is was already loaded. like this

```
<div v-if="$store.getters.currency">
      {{this.$store.getters.currency.name}}
  </div>
```

or declare a new variable in your data like

```
data() {
   return {
       currency: this.$store.getters.currency.name
   }
}
```

now you could call it this way

```
<div v-if="$store.getters.currency">
     {{currency.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: nice one, it's working, but is there a way to make `this.$store.getters.currency` shorter? like we just call `{{currency.name}}`